# Does ${\rm tr}(\Pi \rho) = 1$ imply $\Pi\rho\Pi=\rho$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a density matrix $\rho$ and an orthogonal projector $\Pi$. Is it true that, if $tr(\Pi \rho) = 1$ then it must hold that
$$\Pi \rho \Pi = \rho$$?

If yes, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes its true. Define another orthogonal projector $\Pi_\perp$ such that $\Pi + \Pi_\perp = I$ and write $\rho$ in terms of a spectral decomposition
\begin{equation}
\rho = \sum_k \lambda_k(\rho) |\lambda_k\rangle \langle \lambda_k| \tag{1}
\end{equation}

where we're fine to just consider components such that $\lambda_k(\rho) >0$. Then we have
$$
1 = \text{Tr}(\Pi \rho) = \text{Tr}((I - \Pi_\perp) \rho) = 1 - \text{Tr}(\Pi_\perp \rho) \tag{2}
$$
implying
\begin{align}
0 &= \text{Tr}(\Pi_\perp \rho)\tag{3}
\\&= \text{Tr}(\Pi_\perp \rho\Pi_\perp)\tag{4}
\\&= \sum_k \lambda_k(\rho)\langle \lambda_k|\Pi_\perp\Pi_\perp |\lambda_k\rangle \tag{5}\\&= \sum_k \lambda_k(\rho) \lVert\Pi_\perp |\lambda_k\rangle \rVert^2\tag{6}
\end{align}
where line $(4)$ used the cyclic property of the trace and $\Pi_\perp \Pi_\perp = \Pi_\perp$. Now since $ \lambda_k(\rho) >0$ and $\lVert \cdot \lVert \geq 0$ the above only holds if $ \Pi_\perp |\lambda_k\rangle = 0$ for all $k$. And so
\begin{align}
\Pi \rho \Pi &= (I - \Pi_\perp) \rho (I - \Pi_\perp)\tag{7}
\\&=\rho + \sum_k \lambda_k(\rho) \Bigl(-|\lambda_k\rangle \langle \lambda_k| \Pi_\perp -\Pi_\perp |\lambda_k\rangle \langle \lambda_k| + \Pi_\perp |\lambda_k\rangle \langle \lambda_k| \Pi_\perp\Bigr)\tag{8}
\\&= \rho \tag{9}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Write the eigendecomposition of the state as $\rho=\sum_k p_k u_k u_k^\dagger$, where $\{u_k\}_k$ is a family of orthonormal vectors in the underlying space.

Suppose there is some $u_k\notin \operatorname{supp}(\Pi)$, that is, some $u_k$ such that $\Pi u_k\neq u_k$. Then
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\Pi u_k u_k^\dagger)=\| \Pi u_k\|^2<\|u_k\|^2=1,$$
and thus
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\Pi\rho)=\sum_k p_k \operatorname{Tr}(\Pi u_k u_k^\dagger)< \sum_k p_k=1.$$
It follows that if $\operatorname{Tr}(\Pi\rho)=1$, each $u_k$ must be in the support of $\Pi$, and thus $\Pi\rho\Pi=\rho$.